# How can I repeatedly divide a number by the elements of a list?

Tags: python

```
divisors = []
def check_for_prime(x):
    divisors = [x / d for d in list(range(x)) if x != any([0, 1, x])]
    if isinstance(divisors, float):
        yield x
```

When I try to run this code, it shows an error: 'list object cannot be interpreted as an integer'. How can I fix this so the loop can successfully divide everything?

Comment: can you explain what exactly your code is supposed to do, in words? Your use of `any` is weird, I don't think `any` does what you think it does. Check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

Comment: how can divisors which is a list be an instance of float?

Comment: Also this program is going to give a divdebyZero error straight away, since you are using a range(x) .. divisors is going to be a list as you are storing a output of list comprehension,  so it doesnt make any sense to check if its instance of float.. and i dont understand why you are using yield...

Comment: I'm trying to check if a number is prime. Right now, it's supposed to divide a number x by all integers smaller than it except 0, 1, and the number x itself. If everything inside the divisors list is a float, then the function yields the number x.

Comment: return any(x//i == x/i for i in range(2, x-1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to check if a given number is prime through list comprehension. There are a good bunch of things wrong with your logic-

```py
divisors = [x / d for d in list(range(x)) if x != any([0, 1, x])]
```

I *believe* you're trying to find a list of divisors for `x` here. This makes no sense though, even if I assume that you thought `x != any([0, 1, x])` means "if x is either 0, 1, or `x`" (that's not actually what this code means). Wouldn't that statement always be true? I mean `x` has *got to be* `x` (unless it's `nan`, but that's a different topic).

If you wanted to express "if x is either 0, 1 or `x`" in python, you'd use `if x in [0, 1, x]` (you shouldn't want to though since that makes 0 sense as explained above). Not `any`. Read what [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) does.

To get a list of divisors for `x`, you should instead do-

```py
divisors = [d for d in range(2, math.floor(x/2) + 1) if x % d == 0]
```

Essentially, you start from `2` (not 0 because that's impossible, and not 1 because we want to avoid that for prime checking), and stop at half the given number (because after that point, you can't divide the given number and get an integral result). Throughout this range, you only add those `d` for which `x % d` is 0. I.E, the result is integral. Notice, 6 % 3 is 0, because 3 *is* indeed a divisor of 6.

I have 0 clue what the hell you're trying to do here though-

```py
if isinstance(divisors, float):
    yield x
```

You're checking whether or not `divisors` is a `float`? why? you already know it's a list,  you made it in the previous line.

I think you want to know if the given number is a prime or not. In that case, you can just check if the length of `divisors` is more than 0.

```py
return len(divisors) > 0
```

Edit: As @RiccardoBucco mentioned below. If you don't want the list of divisors at all, you can simply `return` as soon as you find a divisor. A simple loop will suffice for that.

```py
for d in range(2, math.floor(x/2) + 1):
    if x % d == 0:
        # x is not prime
        return False
# x is prime
return True
```

However, DO NOT forget to factor in the exceptional case when `x = 1`, 1 is **not** a prime number. Should be factored in both the `for` loop and the list comprehension method.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco You're right, I should do that and I usually would. But in this case, I was pretty confident OP is looking for a way to check if a number is prime or not through "repeatedly dividing that number", i.e - finding the divisors

Comment: Ok, +1 anyway for the good answer. May I add that it doesn't make sense to generate all divisors if you are trying to check if a number is prime? Once you find a divisor you can stop

Comment: @RiccardoBucco very true

Comment: you need to check only till sqrt x. And there is sieve of erasthones for faster results.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your list as the input argument to range, which expects an integer. Don't do that. Say for i in list.

Answer (score 0):

This will always fail because you're creating a new `list` by using the comprehension in line 3. Line 4 will always evaluate to `False` because a `list` is obviously not a `float`.

Comment: So is there a way to check if all elements in the list are floats?

Comment: `for item in your_list:
    if not isinstance(item, float):
        return False
    return True`

Comment: Also you need to make sure you're checking the items **in** the list _not_ the list object itself.